# Wallet code number

Tags: wallet

I didn't write down my bitcoin wallet code (that long alphanumeric number that was assigned to me) when I installed the software.  How do I find it?

Comment: Which Bitcoin client are you referring to? Do you mean a Bitcoin address?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Bitcoin-Qt client, then the address you might remember seeing is just the first address.  You can see that address, and any others that you've added by clicking "Receive". [Edit: writing this from memory, without a Bitcoin-Qt client to know if I have the right name for the tab.]

If you are using a different client, the steps will vary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about `bitcoind`, the command line client, it was likely just a suggested password for bitcoin.conf, so it doesn't really matter.